# ReCaptchaV2 with PHP

Tags: php

I have the code bellow: For some reason this always resolves to the else

```
echo "Invalid capture, please try again";
```

Where I echo `echo "response before $response"` I get the following nothing.
Directly echoing `file_get_contents($url);` returns ``
`response->success` also prints out nothing

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   echo "Hello submit! \n";
   $user_name = $POST['name'];
   $user_email = $POST['email'];
   $user_subject = $POST['subject'];
   $user_message = $POST['message'];

   $email_from = 'noreply@matterindustries.tech';
   $email_subject = "New form submission from www.matterindustries.tech";
   $email_body = "Name: $user_name.\n
                 Email: $user_email.\n
                 Subject: $user_subject.\n
                 Message: $user_message.\n";
   $email_to = "mail@gmail.com";

   $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: $user_email \r\n";

   $captcha_secret_key = "6Ld5IuUUAAAAAPf3xxxxxxxxxx1112233";
   $response_key = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
   $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$captcha_secret_key&response=$response_key&remoteip=$user_ip";

   $reponse = file_get_contents($url);
   echo "response before $response"
   $reponse = json_decode($response);
   echo "<br>"
   echo "Response after json_decode $response"
   echo "<br>"
   echo

   if($response->success)
   {
      mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
      echo"Message sent successfully";
   }
   else
   {
        echo"Invalid capture, please try again";
   }

 }else{
 echo "You have not submitted yet";
 }
?>
```

Comment: I think you got typo `$reponse` should be `$response`, lines after `$url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelling mistake in your code

```
 $reponse = json_decode($response);
```

check spelling of response

```
if($response->success)
```